# Pass char[] as reference in c

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, reference

I am trying to pass a char[] to a function and mutate it.  The following code compiles and works as expected for my test case, but I get some compiler warnings and I can't figure out how to resolve them.

Code:
    #include 
    #include

```
#define MAX_STRING_SIZE 100

void strOp(char **someString) {
  snprintf( someString, sizeof(someString), "HELLO");
}

int main() {
  char myString[MAX_STRING_SIZE];
  strOp(&myString);
  printf("%s\n", myString);
  return 0;
}
```

Warnings:

```
  echoecho.c: In function ‘strOp’:
  echoecho.c:18:3: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘snprintf’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
     snprintf( someString, sizeof(someString), "HELLO");
     ^
  In file included from echoecho.c:12:0:
  /usr/include/stdio.h:386:12: note: expected ‘char * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
   extern int snprintf (char *__restrict __s, size_t __maxlen,
              ^
  echoecho.c: In function ‘main’:
  echoecho.c:23:3: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strOp’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
     strOp(&myString);
     ^
  echoecho.c:17:6: note: expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[100]’
   void strOp(char **someString) {
```

I've tried a few combinations of using *, *[], and ** and have found a few that work but there are always warnings.  Any ideas how to clean this up?

Comment: C ist strictly pass-by-value. No exceptions! And you cannot pass an array to/from a function in C.

Comment: `sizeof(someString)` is the size of the pointer. You *need* to pass the size separately. And you have 1 star too many, along with  removing the `&` from the array passed.

Comment: you need to indent the `#include` statements by 4 spaces so they will show up.

Comment: in C, when referencing an array, such as in this line: `strOp(&myString);` the name of the array degrades to the address of the first byte of the array.  so the posted code is actually passing a pointer to a pointer, which is an error.

Comment: regarding this line: `snprintf( someString, sizeof(someString), "HELLO");` the 'sizeof(someString)` will return the length of a pointer, not the length of the string,  suggest using: `MAX_STRING_SIZE`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pass pointers to char

try

```
#include<cstdlib>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX_STRING_SIZE 100

void strOp(char *someString) {
snprintf( someString,MAX_STRING_SIZE, "HELLO");
}

 int main() {
 char myString[MAX_STRING_SIZE];
 strOp(myString);
 printf("%s\n", myString);
 return 0;  
 }
```

Comment: You have the error with `sizeof(someString)` which will be 4 or 8, but not `MAX_STRING_SIZE` which you already know..

Comment: Sorry to carp on, but `strlen` will not work because the pointer is to an *uninitialised string*.

Comment: Oddly, this is what I *thought* I tried first but for some reason wasn't getting a mutated result...  must've been some odd typo. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your case the right way to do it would be:

```
#define MAX_STRING_SIZE 100

void strOp(char *someString) {
  /* ... */
}

int main() {
  char myString[MAX_STRING_SIZE];
  strOp(myString);
  printf("%s\n", myString);
  return 0;
}
```

when working with arrays it is usually not necessary to use pointers on them.

However there is a way to do it:

```
#include #include

#define MAX_STRING_SIZE 100

void strOp(char (*someString)[MAX_STRING_SIZE]) {
  /* ... */
}

int main() {
  char myString[MAX_STRING_SIZE];
  strOp(&myString);
  printf("%s\n", myString);
  return 0;
}
```

`someString` is a pointer to an array of `MAX_STRING_SIZE` `char`.